# Pycharm type hinting of custom modules

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, pycharm, type-hinting

Consider this file system:

- a

  - __init__.py
  - b.py
- c

  - __init__.py
  - d.py
- main.py

**b.py**:

```
class B:
  def foo(self):
    print("foo")
```

**d.py**:

```
 class D:
      def bar(self):

        x = None
        """:type : B"""
        #^- working

        y = None
        """:type : a.b.B"""
        #^- nope :(
```

My goal is to use full path to class for type hinting (as shown in second example of :type). Problem of first syntax is that pycharm does not consider duplicities and simply makes hint of "closest" class of desired name. Execution of this project starts in main.py.

**Question:**
How can I make second syntax (absolute path to class) work in PyCharm 3.4.1 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work. I'm surprised that it work for you even though you haven't shown any imports in d.py.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately adding import does not solve this issue. It's possbile to set type of variable in docstring of any class in same project. Only problem is when more than one class of same name exist in project. In that case it's not possible to specify which of classes should be used for code completion/hinting. 

According to official doc https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html should this syntax work (second bullet in "Type syntax" section) but for some reason it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a defect in PyCharm right now.

See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12870